How does german two party consent work regarding audio recording a friend in private?
I find german privacy laws confusing especially regarding the law about recording privately spoken word.
The maximum penalty is a fine or 3 years in prison.
So how is this law applied in a scenario say where one friend records audio of another friend telling a silly joke in their apartment together ?
How is this law used in germany for innocuous scenarios like a friend recording another friend telling a joke etc without asking them / them necessarily being aware?
This question solely concerns the broad wording of the law and the potential heavy penalty in relation to situations of a non nefarious situation such as described above.

This question is similar to: How do you prove a fact at issue in litigation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The person making the recording could turn it on when asking for consent.

I'm asking specifically how this law is used in germany and how it's proven in germany.

You think he-said/she-said problems are resolved differently in Germany?

I really just wanted to know how this law actually worked In germany.

I doubt it comes up much for personal conversations.

That consent did exist or not is a matter of fact, the tribunal will hear the parts and decide on the basis of that if there was consent or not.

The judge is free to decide (freie Beweiswürdigung) how much she trusts each piece of evidence (e.g. witness statements, the content of the recording). In criminal proceedings, the evidence must convince the judge that the crime was committed, not just that the defendant likely committed the crime. In your scenario, there's a good chance that doubt would remain, requiring "not guilty". But the same act may also involve civil law. E.g. if GDPR applies (but it probably doesn't), the person who made the recording would have to prove that consent was given, or risk a fine.

I am asking how the law applies when the content and the situation is innocuous.  A friend telling a joke. Your grandparents arguing about the bread being out of date. Etc.

I'm asking for a German person living with that law to explain to me how it functions in society. I can't imagine ordinary people on a daily basis are being sentenced to 3 years in prison because they didn't get signed consent before they recorded a friend tell a joke or a relative complaining about expensive tomatoes.

@Cardgame482 the rule in society? People are not nuts and don't even try to record each other in private most of the time.

In practice, nobody records other people, unless it is important and they ask for consent on tape, so it's obvious. Why would they record unimportant things? We need recordings of every day life as much as we need to carry guns around in every day life. Not at all. Society functions just fine without it.

Hasn't anyone heard of Lifecasting (a continual live streaming of events in a person's life through digital media) ?  It may be rare but it is real.  People will fight for the right to lifecast their own life.

"I am asking how the law applies when the content and the situation is innocuous. A friend telling a joke. Your grandparents arguing about the bread being out of date. Etc." The answer is that it isn't applied in the mundane circumstances you describe.  No jack-booted government thugs show up to randomly confiscate all recording devices and check that all parties consented because they have more important things to do.  It only becomes an issue... if it becomes an issue.

You have to understand that there is no such thing as "making a secret, innocuous recording". That is as much a contradiction as "innocuous rape". Making a recording without consent is a crime. And all people know that and treat it that way. Even if someone wanted it, not asking or at least openly showing would be a huge breach of trust.
And works exactly as you would imagine it works. People just don't record each other, unless it's openly with consent. Why would we? What would it be good for?
For the video/audio to be legal, you need consent.
Without consent, recordings cannot be used in civil claims, no matter what. Even if they prove your point and don't actually breach any other privacy of the other party and handle nothing but the fact in litigation. They cannot be used. Decided by the highest court: BGH, Urteil vom 18.02.2003 - XI ZR 165/02.
And it can only be used in criminal proceedings if the crime is considered very serious compared to the breach of privacy ("Schwerstkriminilität"). So as an example if you record a thief that steals flowers from your garden, that might not be legal and usable in court without consent, while filming a murderer bury their victim there would certainly be.
In practice, if you want to be safe in court, you need written consent. This is what companies normally do if they record events. In addition, or sometimes as the only way to prove consent, you will have it at the start of the recording. Something like  "This is Jane Doe sitting with prominent book author Max Mustermann, we are recording this on 15.10., welcome John. Hi Jane." This isn't as good as the written form, but it is good enough when it comes to a "he said/she said" situation over missing written consent later.
Assuming the fact that Alice made a video is in evidence, and someone in the video complains, it is on Alice to prove that she had consent of the people subject of the video and was allowed to make that video.
As with many legal matters, in he said/she said situations, the judge will have to make a decision on who they believe more.
The prisons aren't filled with people illegally recording others, because we don't. It was perfectly possible to not take video/audio wherever you go for the last 10.000 years, why would it be different now. Just because you technically can doesn't mean it's a good idea and we have to all the time.

I'm pretty sure people in Germany record people secretly all the time, in particular young people. It's apparently a big issue with cyber bullying.

Yeah, young people will drink, smoke, ride bikes drunk, punch each other... all things illegal, teenagers will be teenagers. Adults don't casually record each other. If you go on YouTube, you will meet tons of people coming to Germany, experiencing the "rude" Germans telling them to not record others in public without consent.

@Roland And then comes the kicker: the police will back up those rude people because they have a right not to be on film but for being caught at the side of the recording (e.g. when not subject matter).

"So as an example if you record a thief that steals flowers from your garden, that might not be legal and usable in court without consent, while filming a murderer bury their victim there would certainly be. ... In practice, if you want to be safe in court, you need written consent."
Does that mean security cameras are not allowed in Germany, even if you have signs up saying that you have security cameras?

Depends. Just putting up a sign does not mean you don't need consent. If someone enters a supermarket with a "we are recording you for security reasons" sign, the act of entering through the door that has such a sign has been taken as "consent" so far, given that the supermarket has a "legitimate interest". If you put up a Ring doobell for example, you are only allowed to capture the very space the user is standing when they ring. If you capture a part of the public street every time someone rings, that is technically illegal.

On TV cop shows, police often get evidence from security cameras near a crime scene. I don't know how realistic this is, but would this be invalid evidence in Germany? Do they have the concept of places with no "expectation of privacy"?

Well, I am sure there are places with zero expectation of privacy, maybe a prison yard or something like that. But it certainly isn't "in public". There is no black and white law here, it is the legitimate interests of the camera owner vs the legitimate interests of the person recorded. If the recording party had a valid legal legitimate interest in recording and the cops have a valid legal reason to see that footage, it will be used in a criminal procedure. But they cannot just go around and ask everyone for footage because "who knows, there might be something on there" US cop show style.

@nvoigt I don't know that you can compare rape to recording. You can record someone doing something innocuous without asking them first.  We just don't have a similar concept in England. If someone recorded me eating a strawberry and i turn round and they are laughing then the police aren't getting involved. This is what I was asking about. Can the criminal law really get involved in recordings without asking first of friends joking and pranking with each other. I think german society is just too alien to our understanding to be honest.

Friends joking and pranking with each other sounds a lot like consent, doesn't it? In that situation, who would go to the police and file a complaint? As with almost any other crime, if you aren't filming a guy screaming "no, no, no, don't record me" right in front of a police officer, they will only act if you go to their office and file a report.

@nvoigt my issue and the reason I asked this ( down voted as usual) question is specifically because the wording of the law is broad and the tariff is punitive. Recording the privately spoken word without consent can be a fine or 3 years in prison is crazy talk. Everyone seems confident that nothing happens in mundane scenarios but the law seemingly could theoretically capture a friend recording audio of another friend telling a silly story and sending it to friend C and that situation reaching a criminal threshold. It just seems extreme to even have the law in the first place.

We don't like a "friend" recording "a friend" and then sending it to another "friend", all behind our backs. That is not how we define friends. That is what enemies do. If you are my friend, there should be no problem figuring out whether I am okay with being recorded.

@nvoigt this doesn't change the fact that it seems like germany has a law whereby it can be illegal to record someone's voice without consent regardless of what was said and why. Thereby the law captures circumstances where no malice was intended. You are in your friends apartment, they are complaining about cheese being expensive. You record them complaining to tell your mutual friend that friend A is ranting again. It's a joke situation. But german law potentially allows for criminal prosecution. This doesn't feel right to me.

@Cardgame482 the key piece you seem to be missing is that the law allows for criminal prosecution... It doesn't mandate automatic escalation to a criminal court of law.  Application of the law, (at least in the US...) generally only occurs when harmonious interpersonal relationships break down.  If you are simply joking around with friends it is ridiculously easy to avoid prosecution.

@Cardgame482 I think you need to look at your countries laws more closely. "I do it all the time wiith friends" does not mean it's generally allowed. You will find that things you do naturally with your friends, punching them, insulting them, filming them secretly, maybe having sex with a few, all are highly illegal activities, if it weren't for your friends consent. If you would do it to a stranger, you would get jail time. That's not a new concept.

@nvoigt is this again the case where you compare the logic of two party consent to recording to rape and assault? A sexual crime and a violent crime are a universe away from recording someone's voice without making them necessarily aware. Similarly taking pictures of each other privately if the subject matter is mundane is not illegal without explicit consent anywhere else but Germany.

I don't know what to tell you. Sure there is a difference in "how bad is it", that's why rape carries sentences from 6 months to ten years, with no possibility to get away with a fine. I have never personally felt the need to secretly film someone. That seems shady at best. But I have also never felt the need to carry an assault rifle and that is legal elsewhere, too. So... the law is what it is, there are no people in prison for pranking their friends, because that is based on consent.

Was there consent is an objective fact
The evidence will show there either was consent or there wasn’t. The burden of proof that there was no consent lies with the prosecution and the standard is similar to the common law beyond reasonable doubt.
Providing the recording is made openly and notoriously rather than covertly, continuing to speak will be taken as consent to the recording.
Of course, someone has to make a complaint for the law to get involved.

"The burden of proof that there was no consent lies with the prosecution" are you sure you are talking about Germany here? This doesn't sound like anything I know from German law. Can you quote something that would support your claims?

@nvoigt But doesn't it depend on civil vs. criminal proceedings? I understand "prosecution" as the latter and it would be new to me that you have to proof you're innocent of a crime in Germany. Then again, we don't have the concept of "beyond reasonable doubt" here. As the High Court repeatedly stated, a verdict doesn't have to be the only possible verdict, just a possible one Civil cases: different story and in fact it happens that a case with both aspects has criminal/civil judges come to entirely different conclusions and that's established to be fine, isn't it?

Assuming the video is in evidence and someone filed a report that this happened without consent, because otherwiese there would be no case... what exactly could the prosecutor possibly do more to prove "no consent"?

@nvoigt introduce evidence

What would you count as evidence for "I wasn't asked. If I had been asked I would have said no"?

@nvoigt That testimony plus cross-examination. That’s what evidence is.

@nvoigt, is there no presumption of innocence, or burden of proof requirement in Germany as there is in the US?  Must a defendant prove that they are innocent?
